# Compare time difference in hour from util Date

Tags: java

I want to compare time difference in hours. Based on current time and time I get from database.

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(“yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss”);
Date date = new Date();
Logger.info(“current time is”,sdf.format(date));
// gives date in 2019-11-06 17:03:54
// dB gives following record
Date successDate = loader.getLastSuccess();
// gives date in 2019-10-31T:56:08.066+0000
```

Both formats are different how to get the time difference any suggestion experts

Comment: This is a good start. Just convert the other date with another `SimpleDateFormat` (probably using the ISO format) and use `Date.getTime()` to get the timestamps and subtract them.

Comment: *"gives date in 2019-10-31T:56:08.066+0000"* I doubt that, since the hour value is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the java-8 date API `Duration` to get the duration between both the dates

```
long hours = Duration.between(date1.toInstant(), date2.toInstant()).toHours();
```

**Note :** It can return negative value also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toHours--)

> the number of hours in the duration, may be negative

[public int getHours()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours--) on `util.Date` is deprecated, so convert them to `Instant` and use `Duration.between` and also i will suggest to use java-8 [Date API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) instead of older version [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours--)

Answer (score 1):

If you want difference in hours as double, you can do this;

```
Date your_date = loader.getLastSuccess();
Date currentDate = new Date();
double hourdifference = (currentDate.getTime() - your_date.getTime()) / 3600000.0;
```

You can get long or int, just change 3600000.0 to 3600000, and make the variable int or long

Comment: It is allowing me to only accep a single answer